# Driving 3 Mosfets with a MSP430FR4133 from 0% to 100% Duty Cycle

Tags: microcontroller, led, mosfet, pwm, mosfet-driver

I'm having an issue with a Mosfet driver that I put together. It is a MSP430FR4133 taking in 3 square wave signals and outputting them at a higher frequency. The new signal is put through 3 separate Mosfet drivers to drive LEDs. The problem I'm having is, when I dim the LEDs the Mosfets output the wrong signal at the 2% - 19% Duty cycle Range. 1% works fine and 20 - 100% work fine. I'm sure that I'm just missing some supporting components but I'm really unsure what I'm missing.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9HBcI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Sorry if the schematic is rough, this is my first time using that software. 
Here is the signal after the MCU

[image]

Here is my issue, after the MOSFET

[image]

Edit - I added a Pull up resistor on the drain and it made the waveform more stable. It now inverts the output of the MOSFET in between 2% and 19% Duty Cycle. I updated the issue picture with the new waveform. It is literally inverted from what its suppose to be.

Edit 2 - A symptom of the problem has been found. The Drain voltage is linear when its functioning properly. It is nearly the full 12 volts when we are at a 1% duty cycle and at 20% duty cycle we are at 10 volts. Going up from there the voltage drops properly. In the Problem area of 2% to 19 % duty cycle the voltage starts at 3.3 volts at 19% then around 16 % raises to 5.6 volts then drops down to 1 volt at 2 %. I originally was using a Launch-Pad for the processing of this application but I have now mounted the processor onto the PCB and I'm getting the same issue. The ground that's connected to the MOSFET is the same ground that is runs through the entire PCB. I'm not sure if a ground issue would cause this problem considering the problem is so repeatable. Another Observation is that the problem is eliminated when I drop my frequency down to 600 hz which is the frequency of the input signal coming into my MCU. The higher the frequency the greater the issue.

Edit 3 - After doing some more research I believe that this issue is called Capacitive False Turn-on. Does anyone have advice as to how to fix this? The traces on my board are really thin because its a prototype board, is there something that I can add in order to fix this issue without getting a new prototype board? I have tried lowering the resistance of the Rg to 10 Ohms and it made the issue happen at 10% duty cycle instead of 20% and 1% is now messed up. It shrunk the problem area but hasnt solved it. When I raise the resistance, the issue gets worse.

Comment: Looks as if the whole scope is wavering all over the place... ;o)

Comment: driver datasheet http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/205/IXD_604-13868.pdf

Comment: I don't see the decoupling caps in your circuit diagram.

Comment: Why do you have a resistor on the gate of the mosfet?

Comment: The LED should have a resister .You have used a big mosfet with lots of capacitance which adds to the LED capacitance .If you pull up the drain experimentaly with say 1K ohm you should see some waveform improvement which will confirm the capacitance issue.

Comment: Sorry, the LED is actually an LED strip. So it has the prerequisite resistance on the strip. There are three MOSFETS with each of them connected to R, G, or B.

Comment: Should the MOSFETS have their own decoupling caps?

Comment: In order to protect the driver. When I run it without the resistor, the driver goes up in smoke :)

Comment: I tried to add the pull up and it did , in fact smooth out the waveform. The issue now is that in that lower range it seems to flip the logic, so it will be dimming correctly until about 10% then itll jump up in brightness in that low range until 1% in which it actually goes to 1%.

Comment: @DerekSpeegle try a different FET.. this one claims to be normal up to 50kHz only, per datasheet. also please provide gate voltage & drain voltage on the same scope shot

Comment: Also, most important, please show your MCU/driver/MOSFET physical circuit. I'll bet your ground structure is iffy.

Comment: What waveform do you get  between the MOSFET Gate and Source?

Comment: Drain Voltage is either 5.6 Volts or 3.3 Volts and Gate Voltage is around 250 mV.  I think RoughBeast may be correct. So, the Drain voltage is the full 12 volts on 1%. Then if you go to the 20% its about 10 Volts.  As you go higher the voltage drops. However, once it drops to 19% it interestingly goes to 3.3 volts. As I drop it further it then goes to 5.6 Volts and drop down to 1.2 Volts as I hit 2%. My theory is that its somehow having an issue with my 3.3 Volt regulator for the MCU and the 5 volts from the USB connection on my Launchpad.

Comment: To answer Bruce's question, the waveform looks exactly like the first picture on my question. Which is the correct Waveform. RoughBeast, I just have my grounds connected by traces on a pcb atm. These are prototype board so having a full ground plane makes it really hard to work with. Normally, I would have a ground plane across the whole board. Should I be separating the ground on these MOSFETS? I didnt think I was working with high enough frequency to worry about that but maybe I should be.

Comment: How's your MCU output pin configured? Push-pull? Open-drain/collector? Does it have internal pullups or pulldowns? If so, what is the resistance?

Answer (score 2):

After much testing I finally found the solution. [This Article](http://www.electronic-products-design.com/geek-area/electronics/mosfets/using-mosfets-as-general-switches) States that :

> For high current MOSFETs the Gate Channel Capacitance can be very high and a rapidly changing drain voltage can produce milliamps of transient Gate current.  This could be enough to overdrive and even damage delicate CMOS driver chips. Having a series resistor is a compromise between speed and protection, with values of 100R to 10K being typical. Even without inductive loads there is dynamic gate current. Also, MOSFETs are extremely susceptible to damage caused by electrostatic discharge and can be damaged irreversibly by a single instance of Gate breakdown. For this reason it is a very good idea to use gate series resistors of 1K to 10K.  This is especially important if the Gate signal comes from another circuit board.

After Reading this I changed my Series Gate Resistor to 1k and the problem vanished entirely. It would appear that when your a higher frequency with a capacitive load you need a higher Series Gate Resistor.

Comment: Are you switching at 10kHz? because that is not a high frequency

Comment: Yea, I'm at 10khz. If the frequency wasn't the issue then it must have been the capacitive load.